# Xamarin.Forms Image Binding in ListView

Tags: image, xaml, listview, xamarin, binding

Hi I'm new to Xamarin and was wondering if someone could give me a hand with this binding code. Here are some of the classes that create the deserialized JSON object.

I want to use the `link` property in the `Image` class (not the `Hit` class) as the binding value in the XAML code (see below).

The ListView.itemSource is assigned with the array `List<Hit> hits`.

```
public class Image
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public string alt { get; set; }
    public string dis_base_link { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Hit
{
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public ProductType product_type { get; set; }
}

public class DemandwareRootObject
{
    public string _v { get; set; }
    public string _type { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Hit> hits { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }
    public List<Refinement> refinements { get; set; }
    public SearchPhraseSuggestions search_phrase_suggestions { get; set; }
    public List<SortingOption> sorting_options { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

this is the XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Gray">
                    <Image Source="{Binding link}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This doesn't work as I'm sure it's referencing the `link` property in the `Hit` class. Ideally I would like it to point to the link property in the image property e.g.

```
 <Image Source="{Binding image.link}"/>
```

does anyone know the correct syntax?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: if each item in the ListView is a Hit, then the "{Binding image.link}" syntax should work.  Are you sure each field is a valid url?

Comment: I think you need to set Items Source on your list view. Ex: ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesCollection}". Then you will have access to the properties of each Image

Comment: Thanks Jason you're right it does work